# Android intent filter drops query string

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I have defined a data tag in my `intent-filter` node of `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<data
    android:scheme="http"
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/path/pageEnum" />
```

the path I am trying to capture is `http://example.com/path/pageEnum?one=1&two=2&three=3`

I am launching the intent from `adb` like so:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW     -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE     -d "http://example.com/path/pageEnum?one=1&two=2&three=3"`

The target activity is launched successfully, but when I call `getIntent().getDataString()` in `onCreate()` the string value is `http://example.com/path/pageEnum?one=1`

All of the query parameters except for the first are dropped.

Is there any workaround to make sure that I get all of the query parameters?

There is nothing in [google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) about this behavior.

Comment: Your `&` pieces might be being eaten by your shell, where you are running the `adb shell` command. Rather than using `adb shell`, write an app that calls `startActivity()` with the desired `Intent`.

Comment: that was the issue, thanks!

Comment: Wrap your adb shell command with single quotes: `adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW     -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE     -d "http://example.com/path/pageEnum?one=1&two=2&three=3"'`

Comment: @SimonMarquis your answer works! Thanks. Should have posted as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap your adb shell command with single quotes:

`adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "http://example.com/path/pageEnum?one=1&two=2&three=3"'`